# Double click to open documents and folders

Tags: macos, trackpad

Before I installed Lion I was able to open folders and documents by using double click/tap on the trackpad. Now it doesn't work anymore. Did this happen to anyone else?

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Does tap to click work in other places?

Comment: Nathan, Ross, Nano: Tap to click is enabled, I did reset, switch off-->turn on, but nothing. Everything else works fine, all other functions from track pad works, I can use click/tap in browsers, 3 fingers drag, etc... Could it be bug? Should I re-install everything once again, or there could be some other solution. appreciate

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that Lion may have reset double-click speed to a faster setting; it could be registering your double-clicks as two single-clicks separated by a pause. Does it help to change the double-click speed (in System Preferences > Mouse) to a slower setting?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure tap to click is enabled:

[image]

If it still doesn't work more information is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Are you unable to select things with a single tap on the trackpad? Does physically clicking still work?

When I installed Lion on my MacBook, it disabled the "tap-to-click" feature and I had to re-enable it in System Preferences > Trackpad.